# Run PowerToys Peek from Terminal

Tags: terminal, quicklook, powertoys

In PowerToys there is a tool called Peek which allows you to preview file contents in Windows Explorer by pressing Ctrl+Space. Contents are shown in separate minimalistic window.

Is there a way to use this Peek from Terminal? i.e. `peek.exe readme.md`.

I aware of *QL-Win/QuickLook* utility with similar functionality, it works fine in cmd, but since I already use PowerToys, maybe I can utilize it's internal Peek to my purpose.